# Media Queries and Animating Text Size

Tags: css, media-queries, font-size

I'm using media queries to change the font size of my nav:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px)
{  

#nav-options{
    margin: 45px 0 0 20px;
    li{
        margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
}

/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px)
{  
#nav-options{
    margin: 45px 0 0 0px;
    li{
        margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
            font-size: 10px;
    }
}
}
```

The problem is, when I change the size of my window, the text animates to the different size. Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: What does it have to do with animating?

Comment: When I change the size of the browser, the font size animates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try to use `max-device-width` and `min-device-width`. It will works only with the screen resolution and not on the window size

Comment: It does work with window size as I am testing it now. I just want to know how to stop the text from animating.

Comment: check if there are any css transitions within your style sheets

Answer (score 0):

Don't change font size. Now you use different size for different resolutions.

Comment: But how can I change the font size for different screen sizes?

Comment: This answer doesnt make any sense.